# When shutdown with my 13.04 with button it does not go off

Tags: shutdown

When shut down on button it does not go off, but ask again do you want to shut down if yes it freezes up to who knows when, if I type cancel shut down is delayed until further I do the same, but if I type suspend from roll down many in upper right corner if goes off?!
I have HP probook, i3 3210, 4gb, bought few days ago and I have deleted suse to install 13.04.
Jovan

Comment: Can you shutdown your PC in the Terminal with sudo shutdown?

Comment: I'll add it as a answer.

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown your PC with either `sudo shutdown` or `sudo halt`.